# C++:How to efficiently return private vector of 1million to several other classes with proper OO

Tags: c++, encapsulation, friend, object-oriented-analysis

I'm trying to write politically correct object oriented code that includes five classes, a few of which need to manipulate a private vector in one of the classes. I was unsuccessful in trying to make friend functions due to circular references, and was wandering if there are better ways. The vector is very large(1 million) and I'm doing 100,000 or so iterations so returning it seems inefficient.

A skeleton of my code is:

```
  class A{
     func(){use a}
     private:
       vector<double> a;
  };

  class B{
    func(){use a and manipulate b};
    ...
    private:
    double *b;
  };

 class C{
   ...
  func(){use a}
  func(){use b}
 };

main(){
 for(j=0; j<500000;j++){
   A a1;
   a1.func(); 
     ....
   B b1;
   C c1;
   b1.func();
   c1.func();
   ....
 }
}
```

These classes have a "has-a" relationship so I can't use inheritance. I eventually plan on putting the declarations in main in another class with a "has-a" relationship.

Thanks

Comment: Define `politically correct object oriented code`.

Comment: Something that an employer would not frown upon. I'm trying to find an efficient way to access the private vector that is in keeping with encapsulation. Although, I've wondered if it might be better to declare the vector as public.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a method in class `A` that returns a reference to the vector:

```
class A {
  public:
    vector<double>& getVector() { return a; }
    ...
```

or

```
    const vector<double>& getVector() const { return a; }
```

if the users of the vector do not modify it.

Returning a reference to a private object is nothing bad as long as it is justified by class design. Roughly speaking, if the fact that there is vector return value is not an implementation detail of `A` class, but something other users of `A` should really be aware of.

Comment: In which case, one might as well make it a public member.

Comment: @juanchopanza, not exactly, having a getter function gives you (a bit) more flexibility. For example, you might have _two_ arrays and return a reference to one of them based on some condition. Or you might decide to refactor class `A` and move the array into another class, which will be included into `A` as a member, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was wondering if this might be a special case of where being a public member might make sense, but I like the idea of returning a reference since the member remains private.